# How to use cron.d file when using Ubuntu

Tags: cron

I have a backup script that I can run successfully manually as root

```
backup perform --trigger confluence --config-file /etc/backup/config.rb --log-path=/var/log > /dev/null
```

In the `/etc/cron.d` folder I have file `confluence_backup` with the following contents

```
# Crontab for confluence_backup managed by Chef. Changes will be overwritten.

0 0 * * * root backup perform --trigger confluence --config-file /etc/backup/config.rb --log-path=/var/log > /dev/null
```

For some reason this backup script will not run. I don't see messages in `/var/log/backup` or in `syslog` for that matter. I tried restart of `cron` service but still the job does not run.

Why is the script not running?

Answer (score 0):

First, have you confirmed that the executable 'backup' is in the root user's PATH variable?